# log out from slim, or slim restart results in blank screen for several minutes

Tags: login, desktop-environment, openbox, strace, slim

I am using slim login manager.

when I log out from my session, or restart slim from the commandline:

```
service slim restart
```

I get blank console for couple of minutes, before the slim login screen appears again.

When I attach to the slim process with strace, I see many "Resource temporarily unavailable" and "Connection timed out" lines:

```
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path=@"/tmp/.X11-unix/X0"}, 20) = -1 ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
close(4)                                = 0
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 4
getsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [212992], [4]) = 0
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/tmp/.X11-unix/X0"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(4)  
    
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(6000), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGUSR1 {si_signo=SIGUSR1, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=5440, si_uid=0} ---
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, {sa_handler=0x55961af808a0, sa_mask=[USR1], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f545cc5afd0}, {sa_handler=0x55961af808a0, sa_mask=[USR1], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f545cc5afd0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 42
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(6000), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
close(4)
```

full strace [here](https://ctxt.io/2/AABQmQk_Eg)

after few minutes slim login screen reappears again, and everything works fine.

When I restart computer, slim works fine the first time, probably because I have autologin in my /etc/slim.conf:

```
auto_login          yes
```

What is going on? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you show us your  `/etc/slim.conf`?  And your `DISPLAY` variable?

Comment: @tukan - here is my slim.conf: https://ctxt.io/2/AABQfYQ6EA

Answer (score 1):

The `slim.conf` file looks fine to me.  Since you did not share the value of your `DISPLAY` variable I'll try to do some guess work.

The format of `DISPLAY` variable is `[host]:<display>[.screen]`.

I think your `DISPLAY` variable is set to `DISPLAY=localhost:0.0`.  After you restart your session it tries to reach it and for whatever reason it can not reach it.

I would recommend changing the `DISPLAY` variable to

`export DISPLAY=:0.0`

Now it will force `Xorg` to use local display and not to search the localhost for it.

To make it permanent you need to adjust `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`.